# Locking issue when using ksession.retract

Tags: java, drools

I currently have an issue with drools (5.6). We're trying to get our rule-engine safe to break downs and deadlocks, but as we allow users to enter drools rules directly, that's kind hard.

Our current issue: When putting something in the condition-part like `eval(myAPI.myMethod("abc"));` which throws an exception. This however causes drools to not run smoothly afterwards.

When we try to get everything back to normal (retracting objects and fact handles and reload them from the database, where we constantly persist the ksession), we get a lock-issue:

When calling `ksession.retract(eventObject);` just nothing happens and debugging shows, that it gets locked at "this.lock.lock()" in `NamedEntryPoint.retract(...):548`

I've tried lots of things to circumvent this, but I don't know how to. Is there anyone out there, that maybe has an answer? Like some config-param, that limits locking time, some method, that allows manual unlocking, or just something, that allows entirely shutting down the current sessions (dispose is not an option, as it states, that is may cause memory leaks if not used before everything was cleaned up).

Any ideas? Thanks and regards,
Kay

Comment: Why does `eval(myAPI.myMethod("abc"))` have (or be permitted) to throw an exception in the first place? Throwing an exception in code that should produce a boolean from data in some Pojo should never throw *unless something completely unforeseen* happens, indicating that your app is up the creek or down-and-out, without a chance for recovery.

Comment: I know, that these methods shouldn't cause any exceptions, but as we allow developers to use our API, which has database access and so on, we need to make sure that missing parameters (null-params, missing params, wrong param types, like non-existent enum items etc.) don't cause any issues. We're currently reworking the API, so less exceptions are thrown, but we can't avoid all of them for some reason (e.g. if the developers doesn't have access to the method he's trying to use there).

Thus, it would be great if we could avoid this "exception crashes drools" issue somehow...

Comment: That's a catch-22. Maybe you can escape by providing a wrapper `boolean failsafe( boolean b )` that catches all exceptions thrown by myMethod & comp. This method should catch, set a flag, log and return false. After all insertions, deletions, retractions: check the flag and undo whatever was done. This will leave the *Engine* in a consistent state, and you are "only" left with the problem of rectifying this last mishap. - You can't fall out of a fireAllRules with an exception and expect everything to be clean and stable.